# How to implement a function that has n number of iterations?

Tags: r

I am trying to implement this function- [f(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o33q.png)

This is what I have so far -

```
func3 <- function(x) {
   sum((x^4 - 16*x^2 + 5*x)/2)
}
```

I need help creating the function so that way I can answer the following questions. I don't understand how to have the function sum the number of n values.

(a) Implement the function $f(x)$ for any value of $n$ ($n$ represent the dimension in this problem)
(b) Let $n=2$ and create a plot of the resulting function with $x_1$ and $x_2$ ranging from $-5$ to $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong. I think what you need is this. x is a vector in n dimensions. You need to calculate the function over the n dimensions (in this case 2). The plot is then a surface plot, which we can make with the raster package.

```r
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- function(x, n) {
  terms <- (x^4 - 16 * x^2 + 5 * x) / 2
  sum(terms[1:n])
}

# calc function over n = 2 dimensions
n <- 2
x1 <- seq(-5, 5, 0.01)
x2 <- seq(-5, 5, 0.01)
z <- matrix(nrow = length(x1), ncol = length(x2))
for (i in seq_along(x1)){
    for (j in seq_along(x2)){
        x <- c(x1[i], x2[j])
        z[i, j] <- f(x, n)
    }
}

# convert matrix to raster for plotting
surf <- raster(z, xmn = min(x1), xmx = max(x1), ymn = min(x2), ymx = max(x2))
levelplot(surf, margin = FALSE, col.regions = terrain.colors(255))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>